# How to define a concept that requires T to have a T::inner member

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-expression

I am learning the newly implemented concepts of C++20 standard using g++ 10.
I am stuck with a simple type requirement. Namely I want to implement a requirement for a template argument `T` to have `T::inner` member name.
Here is my code with error. What is wrong with this simple code and how to fix it?

```
#include<concepts>

template<typename T>
concept ContainsInner = requires
{
  typename T::inner;
};

template<ContainsInner T>
struct S{};

struct Q
{
  int inner;
};

int main()
{
  S<Q> s;     // instantiate S with Q for template type, 
              // which must satisfy the ContainsInner concept.
              // Q indeed contains the inner name but still the compilation fails
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
template<typename T>
concept ContainsInner = requires
{
  typename T::inner;
};
```

is requiring that `T` has a *type* named `inner`. Which gcc tells you in its error:

```
source>:6:12: note: the required type 'typename T::inner' is invalid
    6 |   typename T::inner;
      |   ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

`Q` doesn't have a *type* named `inner`. If what you want is to have a member *variable* named `inner`, then you want:

```
template<typename T>
concept ContainsInner = requires(T t) {
    t.inner;
};
```

Note that this doesn't even check what type it is, just that it exists. Which isn't very useful. Maybe you want to require that it's an `int`:

```
template<typename T>
concept ContainsInner = requires(T t) {
    { t.inner } -> std::same_as<int&>;
};
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is thorough and clarifies the issue.

Comment: Two questions regarding your line of code `{ t.inner } -> std::same_as<int&>`. `same_as` concept expects 2 parameters according to cppreference.com, but you use only one. Still, it works, but why? Why `int&` instead of `int`?

Comment: @IgorPopov: If you provided both template arguments to `std::same_as`, what would it do with the type of the expression being checked?  It’s `int&` because it’s an lvalue (which is necessary from the form of the expression but still must be how you phrase it).